# display dept name instead of dept_id in view asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i had two tables department and employee. I need to show dept_name instead of dept_id with employee details(MVC view).

```
dept_name emp_name email
HR        AAAA    aa@aa.com
Payroll   BBAA    aa@aa.com
```

what to do

thanks in advance

Comment: can you show your code. What you have tried ?

Comment: var query = (from x in sa.employee  join y in sa.dept on x.dept_id equals y.dept_id  where y.dept_id == x.dept_id
 select new { x.emp_id, x.emp_name, x.email, y.dept_id, y.dept_Name }).ToList();

                var empdtls = new List<employee>();
                foreach (var t in query)
                {
                    empdtls.Add(new employee()
                    {    emp_name = t.emp_name, email = t.email,emp_id=t.emp_id,dept_id=t.dept_id
 });
                }


                return View(empdtls);

Answer (score 0):

In your for each loop remove dep_id and use dept_name (assuming you employee class has dept_name)

```
public class employee {
public string emp_name {get;set;}
public string email {get;set;}
public int emp_id {get;set;}
public int dept_id {get;set;}
public string dept_name {get;set;}
}



      var query = (from x in sa.employee 
        join y in sa.dept on x.dept_id equals y.dept_id 
        where y.dept_id == x.dept_id 
        select new { x.emp_id, x.emp_name, x.email, y.dept_id, y.dept_Name }).ToList();
         var empdtls = new List<employee>(); 
         foreach (var t in query) 
         {
         empdtls.Add(new employee() { emp_name = t.emp_name, email = t.email,emp_id=t.emp_id,dept_name=t.dept_name }); 
         } 
         return View(empdtls)
```